# Ruby round integer with different length

Tags: ruby, rounding

I can have different-length integer's... 
For example 1896, or 894...

But how can i convert them to float, so that i have only one symbol after comma?

For example

```
1896 -> 1.9
894 -> 0.9
539 -> 0.5
```

How can i do this on ruby?

Now i do this so:

```
type.TYP_CCM.round(-2).to_s[0].concat(".").concat(type.TYP_CCM.round(-2).to_s[1])
```

But it is bad idea, and is only for 4-digit int...

Comment: Are you simply dividing by 1000, and then rounding the result to 1dp? Don't go via to_s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about that:

```
(1896/1000.0).round(1) # 1.9
(894/1000.0).round(1) # 0.9
(539/1000.0).round(1) # 0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the API:

```
(1234/1000.0).round(1)
```

should give you one decimal digit after the dot.

Even if it were not in the API, you could easily emulate this via

```
(1234/100.0).round() / 10.0
```

or more close to your code:

```
(1234).round(-2) / 1000.0
```

As for ensuring that your output has the format xxxx.y - use **format strings**, http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25

Comment: It will set the decimal at 0. You'll need to divide by `1000.0` to force the result as a float.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, yes, obviously.